# String to Sequence of Tokens

Tags: c#, string, tokenize

I'm parsing command sequence strings and need to convert each string into a string[] that will contain command tokens in the order that they're read.

The reason being is that these sequences are stored in a database to instruct a protocol client to carry out a certain prescribed sequence for individual distant applications. There are special tokens in these strings that I need to add to the string[] by themselves because they don't represent data being transmitted; instead they indicate blocking pauses.

The sequences do not contain delimiters. There can be any amount of special tokens found anywhere in a command sequence which is why I can't simply parse the strings with regex. Also, all of these special commands within the sequence are wrapped with `${}`

Here's an example of the data that I need to parse into tokens (P1 indicates blocking pause for one second):

```
"some data to transmit${P1}more data here"
```

Resulting array should look like this:

```
{ "some data to transmit", "${P1}", "more data here" }
```

I would think LINQ could help with this, but I'm not so sure. The only solution I can come up with would be to loop through each character until a `$` is found and then detect if a special pause command is available and then parse the sequence from there using indexes.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use `Regex.Split` -- can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Why would you not use a set of delimiters? That would trivialize this problem.

Comment: You are more-or-less exactly describing a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).  There should be a fair amount of information on how lexers work and they are relatively simple to implement.

Comment: @Gabe, because I don't have delimiters.

Comment: @Tejs, because the command strings are data shared between several apps and can not be altered to suit my one app that I'm writing.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what's wrong with a regex. Can you post an example where `Regex.Split(str, @"(\${.*?})")` *won't* work?

Comment: @Gabe, why wouldn't you post an answer if you have a solution? Your use of split with your pattern kind of works. It adds empty strings to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `Regex.Split(str, @"(\${.*?})")` and ignore the empty strings that you get when you have two special tokens next to each other.

Perhaps `Regex.Split(str, @"(\${.*?})").Where(s => s != "")` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so as was mentioned in the comments, I suggest you read about [lexers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). They have the power to do everything and more of what you described.

Since your requirements are so simple, I'll say that it is not too difficult to write the lexer by hand. Here's some pseudocode that could do it.

```
IEnumerable<string> tokenize(string str) {

    var result = new List<string>();
    int pos = -1;
    int state = 0;
    int temp = -1;

    while( ++pos < str.Length ) {
        switch(state) {
            case 0:
                if( str[pos] == "$" ) { state = 1; temp = pos; }
                break;
            case 1:
                if( str[pos] == "{" ) { state = 2; } else { state = 0; }
                break;
            case 2:
                if( str[pos] == "}" } {
                    state = 0;
                    result.Add( str.Substring(0, temp) );
                    result.Add( str.Substring(temp, pos) );
                    str = str.Substring(pos);
                    pos = -1;
                }
                break;
            }
    }

    if( str != "" ) {
        result.Add(str);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Or something like that. I usually get the parameters of `Substring` wrong on the first try, but that's the general idea.

You can get a much more powerful (and easier to read) lexer by using something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: Maybe ANTLR is my answer then because that's what I'm trying to go for, something simpler and easier to read/comprehend. I can loop through the string to tokenize the sequences no problem.

Comment: @jlafay, it kindof depends on how powerful you need it to be. If you anticipate things to get more complicated, then use ANTLR. If the algorithm above solves your problem completely, then use a hand written one instead. The code above is better described as a state machine than a loop, and is very very similar to what ANTLR will generate, so you're not likely to gain much in terms of efficiency. It all depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using a little bit of Gabe's suggestion, I've come up with a solution that does exactly what I was looking to do:

```
string tokenPattern = @"(\${\w{1,4}})";
string cmdSequence = "${P}test${P}${P}test${P}${Cr}";

string[] tokenized = (from token in Regex.Split(cmdSequence, tokenPattern)
                      where token != string.Empty
                      select token).ToArray();
```

With the command sequence in the above example, the array contains this:

```
{ "${P}", "test", "${P}", "${P}", "test", "${P}", "${Cr}"}
```